# How to check errorbags which have variable names

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

In Laravel (version 5.0, because of server compatibility) I can use [named errorbags](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#error-messages-and-views) to send errors back to a form on a view where there are multiple forms in the same view (e.g. a login form and a register form). For example, I would do that like this:

**Controller**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, 'loginForm');
    }
    // do something if validation was succesful
}
```

**View** (add this under the login form)

```
@if ($errors->hasBag('loginForm'))
    <ul class="fa-ul">
        @foreach ($errors->loginForm->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

When I do it this way, everything works perfectly fine. However, now I need to do the same thing for a view where I don't know the name of the messagebag. This is a view where I display all the items from a database and each of these items needs a form. (Yes, it is necessary in my case to do it this way).

In particular, the aforementioned controller and view would look more like this:

**Controller**

```
public function login(Request $request, $formId)
{
    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, $formId);
    }
    // do something if validation was succesful
}
```

**View** (add this under each form, the forms are created with a `@foreach()` loop)

```
@if ($errors->hasBag($formId))
    <ul class="fa-ul">
        @foreach ($errors->$formId->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Here, `$errors->hasBag($formId)` works perfectly fine, but `$errors->$formId->all()` doesn't, so my question is: Is there any way of doing this?

### Update 1

`dump($errors->getBags())` gives (the error is in dutch):
[image: image 1]
Thus the bag exists.

`dump($error->$bag)`gives:
[image: image 2]

### Update 2

Now it works, I don't know however what was causing the problem... One thing I changed was adding an underscore before the bag names, because they where numbers.

Comment: What happens if you `dd($errors->$formId)` inside your blade?

Comment: Could you also try to `dd($errors->getBags())` to see if your ViewErrorBag is actually there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I found that the problem was that I was using numbers (id's) for the names of the message bags. The problem was solved by adding an underscore (`_`) before each name so that is became a legitimate variable name.